# Slider not showing captions for generated clones

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have this image slider that was build using bxslider which is supposed to show captions when the mouse hovers over the image. The code works just fine for images that I put in but there is a list of clones generated in the slider for which the captions don't work. I'm not sure how to get them working.

```
           $('.thisOne',this).hover(function() {        
    var title = $(this).attr('title');   
    if (title != undefined && ('' + title).length) {    
        $(this.parentNode).append('<div class="bx-caption"><span>' + title + '</span></div>');                       
    }               
    });
```

The broswer generates a copy of the images with a class 'bx-clone' out the list and appends them the list of images such as the one below.

```
        <ul class="bxslider1">
          <li><img class="thisOne" img src="images/pic1.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dsafkjhsdaflkhdsafkj"/></li>
          <li><img class="thisOne" src="images/pic2.jpg"     title="Lorem ipsum dsafkjhsdaflkhdsafkj" /></li>
          <li><img class="thisOne" src="images/pic3.jpg"     title="Lorem ipsum dsafkjhsdaflkhdsafkj" /></li>
          <li><img class="thisOne" src="images/pic4.jpg"     title="Lorem ipsum dslfakjds;lafkjds;lafkjg;oljdfgopi ds ogijugjdfoi" /></li>
          <li><img class="thisOne" src="images/pic5.jpg"     title="Lorem ipsum dslfakjds;lafkjds;lafkjg;oljdfgopi ds ogijugjdfoi" /></li>
          <li><img class="thisOne" src="images/pic7.jpg"     title="Lorem ipsum dslfakjds;lafkjds;lafkjg;oljdfgopi ds ogijugjdfoi" /></li>
        </ul>
```

I don't know how to get the cpations to show up on top of the duplicate images. If it helps I wrapped my function inside the $(document).ready();  I'm sorry but I don't have a better way of explaining the code.

Comment: Use jquery on() http://api.jquery.com/on/ $('.thisOne',this).on('mouseover',function(){ });

Comment: Like I said it works for the original set of images and not for the ones cloned. mouseover produces the same effect.

Comment: have you tried using with .on ?

Comment: Yeah, I did use it. It brings in the same effect. My problem like I said here is that the clones are not targetted

Comment: Have you used captions:true option? Pls post the code for invoking the slider too.

Comment: No, the captions were just displaying on load along with the image, but my intent was to display them on hover so i added my own code to it.

Comment: It works only for single images not for multiple images. I have tried all sorts of combinations already

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/UGQj8/)

What I have done is, used a custom attribute called **slide** and assigned unique slide numbers to the different images. And on hover try to find the cloned object with the same attribute.

Also your code kept appending the caption on each hover. It's not optimum, so added a check to see if caption is added already.

```
   $('img').hover(function() {        
   var title = $(this).attr('title');   
   var slideNo = this.getAttribute('slide');
   if (title != undefined && ('' + title).length) {    
     var captionAdded = $(this.parentNode).find('.bx-caption');
     if(captionAdded.length == 0){
        var imgObjs = $(this).parents('ul').find('img[slide='+slideNo + ']');
        for(var i=0; i<imgObjs.length; i++){
          $(imgObjs[i].parentNode).append('<div class="bx-caption"><span>' + title + '</span></div>');    
        }
     }
  }               
  });
```